# how to break up a bread recipe?

Tags: bread, retarding-bread

I found this recipe for a [pull apart cheesy bread](http://www.roxanashomebaking.com/pull-apart-cheese-herb-bread-recipe/) that I love. It turned out ok the first time, and I'd like to try it again for a dinner I'm having this week. 
However, I don't have a lot of time to prepare dinner after work (hopefully 1-2 hours max), and I was wondering how to break up the recipe to have it ready for dinner on time. I need to take about a half-day to one-day break in the middle; where/how do I split this recipe up??
Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 7):

That looks pretty tasty.

If you only need a few hours you can just put the dough in the fridge when it does its first rise.

The cold will make it rise more slowly and buy you some time. Make sure to put the dough in a little bit over-sized bowl so it doesn't explode out if it rises more than expected.

In general letting dough rise for extra time like this will result in a more open texture. This can be good or bad depending on the style of bread but it seems like it will be fine with this particular bread.

Comment: You may want to add that for long rises less yeast than in the original “warm/fast” recipe is used.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go the route of prebaked goods. Prepare your bread up to and including the baking step, but cut the actual baking short by about a third - you'll want the bread to have risen fully and stabilised, but not browned too much. After that, keep it cool (possibly in an air-tight container), and just finish baking it on the day.

Nota Bene: I haven't tried this myself - might be advisable to give it a go before it counts.